# React Native FlatList error updating state "undefined is not an object (evaluating ......)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, flatlist

Building an app and needed to update the data state being rendered in a FlatList. Things were not working as I expected so I broke everything down to a simple example to better understand what was going on.

I feel like I am missing something. I determined from testing in this sample app that Flatlist is looking for an ordered key and has to be exactly ordered starting at 0 and so on...

My question is what am I missing? Is this actually a concrete requirement or do I something configured or coded incorrectly? I have not found any documentation stating this requirement of a very well ordered key.

Here is an example of the issue. If you click on the last item **44**, you receive `undefined is not an object` as the lookup does not work to the state.

Full code example below;

**Post**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, UIManager, Platform, LayoutAnimation, Modal, Alert, Linking, Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, Image, TextInput, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";
import { FlashList } from "@shopify/flash-list";
import { List, ListItem, Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import ParsedText from "react-native-parsed-text";
import AntDesign from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";

class Post extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { liked, likeCount } = nextProps;
    const { liked: oldLiked, likeCount: oldLikeCount } = this.props;

    // If "liked" or "likeCount" is different, then update
    return liked !== oldLiked || likeCount !== oldLikeCount;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.liked);
    return (
      <View key={this.props.postid} style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.props.onPressLike(this.props.postid)}
        >
          <AntDesign
            name="like2"
            size={20}
            color={this.props.liked ? "royalblue" : "black"}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> {this.props.postid}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home**

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [
        {
          postid: "0",
          date: "115255668551",
          message: "My Post 1 was 4",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xa",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "true",
        },
        {
          postid: "1",
          date: "215255668551",
          message: "My Post 2",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xb",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
        {
          postid: "2",
          date: "315255668551",
          message: "My Post 3",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xc",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "true",
        },
        {
          postid: "3",
          date: "415255668551",
          message: "My Post 4",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xd",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
        {
          postid: "44",
          date: "515255668551",
          message: "My Post 44 does not work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xe",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
      ],
      postsThisIsWorking: [
        {
          postid: "0",
          date: "115255668551",
          message: "My Post 0",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xa",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "true",
        },
        {
          postid: "1",
          date: "215255668551",
          message: "My Post 1",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xb",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
        {
          postid: "2",
          date: "315255668551",
          message: "My Post 3",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xc",
          commentCount: "2",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "true",
        },
        {
          postid: "3",
          date: "415255668551",
          message: "My Post 3",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xd",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
        {
          postid: "4",
          date: "515255668551",
          message: "My Post 4",
          uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583xe",
          commentCount: "1",
          likeCount: "1",
          liked: "false",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const { date, message, uid, postid, liked } = item;
    console.log("---index-----", index);
    return (
      <Post
        postid={postid}
        liked={liked}
        date={date}
        message={message}
        uid={uid}
        onPressLike={this.handleLikePost}
      />
    );
  };

  handleLikePost = (postid) => {
    console.log("----posts----", this.state.posts);
    console.log("---postid---", { postid });
    let post = this.state.posts[postid]; //error with undefined (evaluating post liked) ----
    console.log("----post----", post);
    const { liked, likeCount } = post;

    const newPost = {
      ...post,
      liked: !liked,
      likeCount: liked ? likeCount - 1 : likeCount + 1,
    };

    this.setState({
      posts: {
        ...this.state.posts,
        [postid]: newPost,
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.posts);
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={Object.values(this.state.posts)}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, postid) => postid}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: This is not going to solve your issue but when you **increase** and **decrease** your like count you're adding a **integer** to a **string** (`likeCount` + `1`)

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with FlatList, or with React for that matter.  Your `posts` is defined as an array in the constructor, but you're trying to access it as an object (`this.state.posts[postid]`). (Note that `postid` contains string values, not numbers, which would have allowed array access to work like that if the `postid`s were always sequential integers starting with zero.  Though that seems unlikely in real usage.)

To access it like that, your data structure should be

```
posts: {
  "0": {postid: "0", likeCount: 1, etc: "etc"},
  "1": {postid: "1", likeCount: 1, etc: "etc"}
...
}
```

(Later in your code you have a `setState` that also assumes `posts` is an object using the above format; it's only the state data in your constructor that's in an array.)

Answer (score 0):

The initial state of the `posts` is a **array**. When you're updating the state in `handleLikePost` you're setting the `posts` to a **object**.

You could do something like this to work with the array. Map over all the posts and modify the post if the **id** is the same. This will return a new array which you can then set to the state.

```js
handleLikePost = (postidToUpdate) => {
  const updatedPosts = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
    if (post.postid !== postidToUpdate) return post;

    const updatedLikeCount = post.liked
      ? parseInt(post.likeCount) - 1
      : parseInt(post.likeCount) + 1;

    return {
      ...post,
      liked: !post.liked,
      likeCount: updatedLikeCount.toString(),
    };
  });

  this.setState({
    posts: updatedPosts,
  });
};
```

I updated the likeCount to parse the int for adding and subtracting. And when returning the new post convert it back to a string.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out how to properly do the lookup on the object, I needed to use the index which is assigned starting at 0 as the rows are rendered. Works perfectly now...

```
handleLikePost = index => {
    let post = this.state.posts[index]   //lookup by index
    const { liked, likeCount } = post
    const newPost = {
        ...post,
        liked: !liked,
        likeCount: liked ? likeCount - 1 : likeCount + 1
    }
    this.setState({
        posts: {
            ...this.state.posts,
            [index]: newPost
        }
    })
}
```